# Is it possible to change the content database of an existing SharePoint '07 web app?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Disclaimer: I'm very much an accidental SharePoint admin so I greatly appreciate your patience.

My SharePoint farm's database server is EOL and about to die. I have managed to get the config database (SharePoint_Config) moved over to the new database server and even managed to get the Central Administration site to use the new database server. I have even added the new database server to the farm as a content database server. My problem right now is with the web app's content database (WSS_Content). I already have a copy of the content database setup and ready to go on the new database server but, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to change the SharePoint web app's database over to it.

Is this even possible? If so, how would I do it? If not, would I have to create a new web app and then restore (and overwrite) its WSS_Content database with my existing one?

Answer (score 1):

Read Microsoft's advice on this, and follow it!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725%28office.12%29.aspx